# Migrating to a new way of identifying devices

Tags: iphone, ios, algorithm, security, encryption

I have a database of users that are identified by their device udid (which got deprecated in iOS 5). I need a new way to identify devices that will **not** generate strings that already exist in my database.

The udid used to be `SHA1(SerialNumber + IMEI + WiFiAddress + BluetoothAddress)`.

Is it safe to use the output of something like `MD5(MACAddress)` as my new way to identify devices? From what I've read it seems like MD5 and SHA-1 output different lengths of strings (respectively 128 and 160 bits), but I'm just making sure I'm not missing anything here. I really don't want to end up with duplicate identifiers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `SHA1(MAC | 0001)` instead of the previous one. The chance of creating a SHA1 that already exists is unlikely to the extreme, as it would indicate a real problem in the SHA1 algorithm (a collision). Note: I presume that + means concatenation, I've used | as concatenation.

You can increase the counter (in characters or something else, try for 4 bytes) at the end if you need another unique identifier.

Although MD5 is probably safe enough for this purpose, I would still try and avoid the use of this broken hash - just keep with SHA1 (or move to SHA-256).

Comment: I don't have access to any of the values that used to be part of the UDID hash. I would assume the MAC address is already unique by itself, can't I just MD5 it and since the outputted string's length is different from SHA1 theres no way it will collision with the old identifiers?

Comment: Same thing: if the input is different, a hash will give you a unique value. Then again: the MAC already is the unique value, so you would only do this when you want a shorter value than the MAC address, or if you don't want to store the MAC address for privacy reasons. Removing bytes from the output of the hash obviously makes the chance of collisions grow. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Why `SHA1(MAC | 0001)` instead of just `SHA1(MAC)`? What were you referring to when you said "broken hash"? The MD5 encoding algorithm?

Comment: Yes, I was referring to MD5 when I said it was broken. It's unlikely that it is a huge problem in the current situation, but MD5 might loose even more strength, and using a truly secure hash makes proving the correctness that much easier. As for the counter: it's often used for e.g. key derivation. It's usefull if you want to have a second identifier later on. Of course, as you could always add any data to get a different hash, you may as well add the counter later - if required at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just use MAC address of device.. its unique.. if you don't know how to get MAC address of device see this code -

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <net/if_dl.h>

- (NSString *)getMacAddress
{
  int                 mgmtInfoBase[6];
  char                *msgBuffer = NULL;
  size_t              length;
  unsigned char       macAddress[6];
  struct if_msghdr    *interfaceMsgStruct;
  struct sockaddr_dl  *socketStruct;
  NSString            *errorFlag = NULL;

  // Setup the management Information Base (mib)
  mgmtInfoBase[0] = CTL_NET;        // Request network subsystem
  mgmtInfoBase[1] = AF_ROUTE;       // Routing table info
  mgmtInfoBase[2] = 0;
  mgmtInfoBase[3] = AF_LINK;        // Request link layer information
  mgmtInfoBase[4] = NET_RT_IFLIST;  // Request all configured interfaces

  // With all configured interfaces requested, get handle index
  if ((mgmtInfoBase[5] = if_nametoindex("en0")) == 0)
    errorFlag = @"if_nametoindex failure";
  else
  {
    // Get the size of the data available (store in len)
    if (sysctl(mgmtInfoBase, 6, NULL, &length, NULL, 0) < 0)
      errorFlag = @"sysctl mgmtInfoBase failure";
    else
    {
      // Alloc memory based on above call
      if ((msgBuffer = malloc(length)) == NULL)
        errorFlag = @"buffer allocation failure";
      else
      {
        // Get system information, store in buffer
        if (sysctl(mgmtInfoBase, 6, msgBuffer, &length, NULL, 0) < 0)
          errorFlag = @"sysctl msgBuffer failure";
      }
    }
  }

  // Befor going any further...
  if (errorFlag != NULL)
  {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", errorFlag);
    return errorFlag;
  }

  // Map msgbuffer to interface message structure
  interfaceMsgStruct = (struct if_msghdr *) msgBuffer;

  // Map to link-level socket structure
  socketStruct = (struct sockaddr_dl *) (interfaceMsgStruct + 1);

  // Copy link layer address data in socket structure to an array
  memcpy(&macAddress, socketStruct->sdl_data + socketStruct->sdl_nlen, 6);

  // Read from char array into a string object, into traditional Mac address format
  NSString *macAddressString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X",
                                macAddress[0], macAddress[1], macAddress[2],
                                macAddress[3], macAddress[4], macAddress[5]];
  NSLog(@"Mac Address: %@", macAddressString);

  // Release the buffer memory
  free(msgBuffer);

  return macAddressString;
}
```

Here is my blog post on same topic - http://www.makebetterthings.com/iphone/how-to-uniquely-identify-an-ios5-device/

Comment: I guess I should have specified that I already know how to get the MAC address. My question was more about the possibility that MD5-ing a MAC address might collision with a previous udid.

Comment: MD5ing the MAC address will give you a completely new thing. it will not collide with your previous udids